# Writing to multiple RenderTarget2D's from HLSL shader

Tags: xna, hlsl, post-processing, rendertargets

I need to write to two render targets: one for colour and another for depth+normal (for post-processing).  I have a problem, though.  Both targets seem to be getting the value output by COLOR0, while the second should logically be getting the value from COLOR1.  What did I do wrong?

RT Initialization:

```
renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(device, gameResolution.Width, gameResolution.Height, false, graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat, DepthFormat.Depth24);
extraTarget = new RenderTarget2D(device, gameResolution.Width, gameResolution.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);
```

Using RTs:

```
Device.SetRenderTargets(new RenderTargetBinding(renderTarget), new RenderTargetBinding(extraTarget));
```

Relevant HLSL:

```
struct Pixel
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float4 Extra : COLOR1;
};

Pixel PS(Middle input)
{
    Pixel output;

    // perform other shader code

    output.Color = float4(totalDiffuse * matDiffuseColor * color.rgb + totalSpecular * matSpecularColor, color.a);
    output.Extra = float4(input.Position.z / input.Position.w, clippedNormal);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your render targets directly:

```
Device.SetRenderTargets(renderTarget, extraTarget);
```

Comment: I tried this first, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure that your graphics card supports more than one render target? I think that your code is correct.

Comment: How do I check for this?

Comment: Try to use this tool: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/graphics_profile_checker

Comment: Okay.  All it tells me is that both Reach and HiDef modes are working (I am using HiDef).

Comment: pfff It seems that you graphic card supports everything that is necesery. And what about this? renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(device, gameResolution.Width, gameResolution.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8);

Comment: Nope, no change.

Comment: It turns out some combination of these things led it to work :)

Comment: @Boreal Do you think you could spare the time to say which? If you propose an edit to Vodacek's post which details the combination, you'll be able to help other people who had your same problem in the future who find this answer.

Comment: I second proposing edits for the sake of prosperity.

Comment: It worked for a little while, then I changed it a bit.  It didn't work after that, so I tried to go back, but now I can't remember how I did it.  It doesn't matter to me, though, because I don't need it anymore.